# What does int type convert to void* mean in pthread_create()?

Tags: c, pthreads

What does such code mean:

```
int main() {
    typedef int UDTSOCKET;
    UDTSOCKET recver;
    pthread_create(&rsvthread, NULL, recvAndSend, (void *)(unsigned long)recver);
    return 0;
}

void* recvAndSend(void* usocket)
{
    UDTSOCKET recver = (UDTSOCKET)(unsigned long)usocket;
}
```

Such code is right? What does `(void *)(unsigned long)recver)` mean, how can `unsigned int` convert to `void*`, and how can `void*` convert to `UDTSOCKET` in

```
UDTSOCKET recver = (UDTSOCKET)(unsigned long)usocket;
```

I think it should be

```
pthread_create(&rsvthread, NULL, recvAndSend, (void *)((unsigned long*)&recver));
```

and

```
void* recvAndSend(void* usocket)
{
    UDTSOCKET recver = (UDTSOCKET)(unsigned long)(*usocket);
}
```

Someone can explain it?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach does pass by value, the second does pass by reference.

**Note**: The way how the data is passed to the thread function has an essential impact on how the variable can be used after the call to `pthread_create()` had returned.

When *passing by value* the variable's value is copied to the stack **during** the call to `pthread_create()`, which has the effect, that the original variable could be used again immediately after the calls return.

If *passed by reference* the value pointed to by reference isn't copied immediately, but at a later point in time, typically **after** `pthread_create()` had returned. This dues to the asynchronous nature of the way the thread's function (as passed to `pthread_create()`) is started, so the variable which's address had been passed in could **not** be reused immediately. If it shall be reused, access to it needs to by synchronised.

---

The first approach makes use of the fact that on some platforms the size of an integer is less or equal the size of a pointer.

This might work or not.

If going this way, make sure to use an integer type which is guaranteed to be of the same size as  pointer. That is `intptr_t` for signed and `uintptr_t` for unsigned integers.

To pass in the data:

```
#include <stdint.h> /* for intptr_t */

...

pthread_create(&rsvthread, NULL, recvAndSend, (void *)((intptr_t) recver));
```

To pull out the data:

```
void * recvAndSend(void * pvsocket)
{
  UDTSOCKET recver = (UDTSOCKET) ((intptr_t) pvsocket);
  ...
```

---

The second approach is the portable way to go, assuming we are doing C, do the following

to pass in the data:

```
pthread_create(&rsvthread, NULL, recvAndSend, &recver);
```

to pull out the data:

```
void * recvAndSend(void * pvsocket)
{
  UDTSOCKET recver = *((UDTSOCKET *) pvsocket); /* First cast to pointer to UDTSOCKET, then dereference this pointer to read out what it ispointing to. */
  ...
```

Comment: hi alk, thank you very much, i understand this now, you analyse this problem deeply and i understand it totally, thank you very much

Comment: @xiaosu: You are welcome .. and if you feel it answers your question feel free to accept this answer by clicking the white check-mark.